# Some (not all) fallback CSS properties disappearing (create-react-app)

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, fallback

I'm working on a site built with create-react-app, and deployed to Heroku. There are some CSS properties I've used along with fallbacks, to support older browsers, specifically when using `clamp`.

```
#npp-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 6vw;
  margin-top: clamp(80px, 6vw, 300px);
}
```

You can see there's a fallback for margin-top in case the browser doesn't understand the clamp calculation. On localhost, it works perfectly, here's a shot of the element properties in the chrome inspector:

[image: dom properties]

But on the deployed site, the fallback has disappeared, making the page render incorrectly on older browsers. I tried adding other properties with fallbacks (z-index and padding), and the z-index worked, padding didn't. Here's code:

```
#npp-container {
  z-index: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0;
  padding: clamp(0px, 0px, 0px);
  margin-top: 6vw;
  margin-top: clamp(80px, 6vw, 300px);
}
```

and the result in chrome when deployed:

[image: dom elements]

CSS fallback properties are working fine in other places in this project. Is there some issue with fallbacks specifically with margin and padding? Is webpack stripping out the fallbacks for some reason? , I'm pretty stuck.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue where 0px inside a clamp() is being turned into just 0, which is unreadable to the browser. Having to implement some workarounds which are far from ideal